# What are these two numbers when initializing a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

What does this mean?

```
vector<int> scores(10, 0);
```

The comment says it initializes all 10 elements to 0. Does that mean the size of the vector is 10, then brought down to 0?

Also, for `push_back`:

```
scores.push_back(0);
```

Is this adding more memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Creating a 10 element vector to hold scores.\n";
//initialize all 10 elements to 0
vector<int> scores(10, 0); 
cout << "Vector size is :" << scores.size() << endl;
cout << "Vector capacity is:" << scores.capacity() << endl;

cout << "Adding a score.\n";
//memory is reallocated to accommodate growth
scores.push_back(0); 
cout << "Vector size is :" << scores.size() << endl;
cout << "Vector capacity is:" << scores.capacity() << endl;
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code and see the results?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation before asking? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Read as: `10` copies of the `int` value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) creates a vector of ten elements, and sets *each element* to zero.

As for the [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) call it *may* cause more memory to be allocated. (See the linked reference for when it happens.)

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean the size of the vector is 10, then brought down to 0?

No, it means the size is 10, and each element is initialised with the value 0.

> Is this adding more memory?

It's increasing the *size* of the vector. If there is enough *capacity* (i.e. if enough memory has already been allocated for the new element), it will simply use that memory. Otherwise, a larger block of memory will be allocated, and the elements moved into it, so that the new element can be placed after them.